# Mongodb | populate post with comment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm making a post/comment system where I want users to be able to comment on posts (called 'captures' in my case).

I currently have everything setup except for the populating of the posts.

I can add comments on a seperate document and I got them refrenced, but when I try to add the populate methode, it doesn't do anything:

```
router.get('/captures/:capture', function(req, res){
         Capture.findOne({_id: req.params.capture}, function(err, data){
            if(err) 
                throw err;
             req.capture.populate('comments');   
             res.json(data);
        });
     });
```

When doing this, it doesn't give any errors, but it also doesn't populate.
I simply get the id's of the comments, but it doesn't populate the 'capture'.

```
console.log($scope.capture.comments);
```

gives:

```
["5744bafc1460f5bf18c17ac0", "5744bd4cfcd57403198f0987"]
```

This is my full code:

**capture.js route:**

```
var Capture = require('../models/capture');
var Comment = require('../models/comment');

module.exports = function(router) {
    router.post('/captures', function(req, res){
        var capture = new Capture();
        capture.birdname = req.body.birdname;
        capture.place =  req.body.place;
        capture.userId = req.body.userId;
        capture.author = req.body.author;
        capture.picture = req.body.picture;
        capture.created_at = new Date();


        capture.save(function(err, data){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            console.log(req.body);
            res.json(data);
        });
    });

    // Map logic to route parameter 'capture'
    router.param('capture', function(req, res, next, id) {
        var query = Capture.findById(id);

        query.exec(function (err, capture) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (!capture) { return next(new Error("can't find post")); }

            req.capture = capture;
            return next();
        });
    });
    // Map logic to route parameter 'comment'
    router.param('comment', function (req, res, next, id) {
        var query = Comment.findById(id);

        query.exec(function (err, comment) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (!comment) { return next(new Error("can't find comment")); }

            req.comment = comment;
            return next();
        });
    });  

    router.get('/captures/:capture', function(req, res){
         Capture.findOne({_id: req.params.capture}, function(err, data){
            if(err) 
                throw err;

==========> As you can see here, I'm trying to populate the given id 
==========> with the comments. Currently when I console log on my capture,
==========> it only gives back the id, but I want it to be populated with
==========> the corresponding comments.

             req.capture.populate('comments');   
             res.json(data);
    });
 });

    router.post('/captures/:capture/comments', function(req, res, next){
        var comment = new Comment();
        comment.body =  req.body.body;
        comment.userId = req.body.userId;
        comment.author = req.body.author;
        comment.created_at = new Date();
        comment.capture = req.capture;

        comment.save(function(err, comment) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }

            req.capture.comments.push(comment);
            req.capture.save(function(err, capture) {
                if (err) { return next(err); }

                res.json(comment);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

**capture model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var captureSchema = Schema({
    birdname: {type: String, required: true},
    place: String,
    userId: String,
    author: String,
    picture: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    created_at: Date,
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Capture', captureSchema);
```

**comment model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var commentSchema = Schema({
    body: String,
    userId: String,
    author: String,
    created_at: Date,
    capture: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Capture'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for this:

```
Capture.findOne({_id: req.params.capture}, function(err, data)
```

Just do the following, and it should work:

```
router.get('/captures/:capture', function(req, res) {
        req.capture.populate('comments', function (err, capture) {
        res.json(capture);
    });
});
```